Nginx Basic Authentication is not working
I wish I could add a better description, but Nginx Basic Authentication is simply not working. No password prompt shows. I have searched the interweb for similar questions, but can't find anything related. I have followed this general tutorial and looked at other tutorials which are almost identical.
I have the .htpasswd file created in location /etc/nginx/snippets/.htpasswd, and the following in my root location block:
location / {
  auth_basic "Administrator Login";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/snippets/.htpasswd;
}

systemctl reload nginx, no login prompt appears, just the page that is supposed to display after login. I have tried in another location, but same. Any ideas? Thanks.

Show full server block config

Are you testing with a URL that points to the location where you have added the authentication?

Solved, thanks for answers.

I created a new server, and auth is working. I really don't know why it wasn't working on the previous server, as I was using the same config. Anyway:
location / {
  auth_basic "Login";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

